# Adding a wireless NIC to a Debian router

Tags: linux, wireless, networking, router, pcie

I'm looking for a wireless network card to add to my Debian router. I'll be using it to create an access point, so it has to have a chipset that supports AP mode on linux. It can be PCIe x1 or PCI and the bandwidth should be at least 300mb. I assume a USB device wouldn't be a good fit for an AP, but the motherboard does support USB 2.0. I'd like something cheap for now, but might consider something more high performance later on. (I've seen some decent-looking cards for around $30)

The most devices connected at the same time would be arount 8-10. The part I'm most uncertain about is the performance and throughput. I'm not really sure how to figure out how well a wireless card would perform without testing it, so I'd appreciate any tips about it.